# Map JAX-RS @PathParam to POJO Constructor With Annotations

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, path-parameter

I want to create an endpoint which has a `PathParam` that automatically calls the constructor of an object to be injected, which has a constructor of a String argument.  To spell it out in code:

Here is the resource

```
@GET
@Path("/{apiVersion}" + "/item")
public Response version(@PathParam("apiVersion") APIVersion apiVersion) {
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

I want the String to automatically be used in a call to the APIVersion constructor.  In the `APIVersion` class

```
public APIVersion(String apiVersion) {
   this.versionString = apiVersion;
}
```

Is it possible to do with only access to annotations?  I do not have access to the `ResourceConfig`.

Comment: Does this not work? It _should_.

Comment: Yes it does, thank you!  I had a separate Jersey error that had masked this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, without any annotations other than `@PathParam`, so the example you've given should work as-is. See https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2271 (emphasis mine) :

> In general the Java type of the method parameter may:
>
> 1. Be a primitive type;
> 2. **Have a constructor that accepts a single String argument;**
> 3. Have a static method named valueOf or fromString that accepts a single
>      String argument (see, for example, Integer.valueOf(String) and
>      java.util.UUID.fromString(String));
> 4. Have a registered implementation of
>      javax.ws.rs.ext.ParamConverterProvider JAX-RS extension SPI that
>      returns a javax.ws.rs.ext.ParamConverter instance capable of a "from
>      string" conversion for the type. or
> 5. Be List, Set or SortedSet, where T satisfies 2 or 3 above.
>      The resulting collection is read-only.

Comment: Thank you yes all of these work!  And you are right, this does work as in my code sample, I had a different Jersey error that was making me think this did not work.